# Passing a method as an argument in Scala

Tags: scala

This seems like it should be fairly straightforward, but I can't figure out how to write it.

I'd like a function like the following, which finds either the `max` or `min` of `seq`.

```
def maxOrMin_1(seq: IndexedSeq[Int], maxMin: IndexedSeq[Int] => Int): Int = maxMin(seq)
```

But instead of `maxMin` as a function, I'd like it to be a method of `IndexedSeq` so that I could write:

```
def maxOrMin_2(seq: IndexedSeq[Int], maxMin: IndexedSeq[Int] => Int): Int = seq.maxOrMin
```

But the compiler says `value maxOrMin is not a member of IndexedSeq[Int]`.

Furthermore, when I try to call `maxOrMin_2` (assuming I could figure out how to write it) like this:

```
maxOrMin_2(IndexedSeq(1, 2, 3), IndexedSeq.max)
```

I get a compiler message: `value max is not a member of object IndexedSeq`.

I'd appreciate knowing how to write these.  Thanks.

**Update:** I just discovered that I can solve the calling problem like this.

```
maxOrMin_2(IndexedSeq(1, 2, 3), (xs: IndexedSeq[Int]) => xs.max)
```

That strikes me as a bit wordy. But unless there's a better way, I guess it will do.

**Update:** Now that I see how to call it, `maxOrMin_1` works fine.

```
maxOrMin_1(IndexedSeq(1, 2, 3), (xs: IndexedSeq[Int]) => xs.max)
```

Is there a better answer than this?

Comment: In general, the answer will probably be something like your "update"; that is "functional programming". But that said, for any real-world problem, i'd encourage you to take a step back and really look at the types and function signatures involved to make sure what you're trying to do make sense. In a strongly-typed language like Scala, it looks odd when you call a function "fooOrBar" and then actually allow it to perform not only foo and bar, but any baz passed in.

Comment: I want `max` or `min`. Is there a way to limit the parameter to just those? The bigger picture: this is part of minimax where one takes either max or min depending on the player. I know minimax can be written so that one takes only, e.g., `max`, but if I wanted it like this, how could it be improved?

Comment: why not pass a boolean to choose?

Comment: I thought of that and decided it was uglier. But it would certainly work. Since this function is defined within another function, there is no chance that _someone else_ will misuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier to simply call `max` or `min` methods directly, rather than via a function. So instead of:

```
val input = IndexedSeq(1, 2, 3)

maxOrMin_1(input, (xs: IndexedSeq[Int]) => xs.max)
maxOrMin_1(input, (xs: IndexedSeq[Int]) => xs.min)
```

you just call directly:

```
input.max
input.min
```

If you still want the original function, you can make the calls more concise by currying (separate argument list for the input and for the function) which produces better type inference in Scala:

```
def maxOrMin_1(seq: IndexedSeq[Int])(maxMin: IndexedSeq[Int] => Int): Int = maxMin(seq)
```

then call as follows:

```
maxOrMin_1(input)(_.max)
maxOrMin_1(input)(_.min)
```